# how do I make a sphere rotate around another sphere in ursina, python

Tags: python, ursina

```
from ursina import *

# update sphere_2 rotation
def update():
    line.rotation_y += 1
    sphere_2.rotation_y += 1

app = Ursina()
sphere_1 = Entity(model = 'sphere',scale = 2)
# try to make sphere_2 follow the lines rotation
line = Entity(model = 'line',scale = 4,y = -1)
sphere_2 = Entity(model = 'sphere',scale = 1,x = -2)
app.run()
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], read about [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Parent sphere_2 to sphere_1. `sphere_2.parent = sphere_1` to make position, rotation and scale relative to sphere_2. Or `sphere_2.world_parent = sphere_1`, if you want to keep the original transformation intact after parenting it.

Comment: for the sphere_2 to rotate around sphere_1. Do I need to add any mathematical rotation updates?

Comment: No, just parent it and rotate the parent. So if it has a child at position (0,0,1) for example, and you rotate the parent, any children will rotate with it, around the parent's axis.